# what are other ways of doing navigation in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub

I am experimenting with flutter and i find flutter navigating between screens difficult what are other ways of doing it.

```
class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('First Screen'),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: RaisedButton(
      child: Text('Launch screen'),
      onPressed: () {
        // Navigate to second screen when tapped!
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: https://flutter.io/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics/ They didn't intentionally make it difficult ;-) Navigation is just a complex topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at plugin called fluro which has some advance features as well
https://github.com/theyakka/fluro

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two methods to navigate from one screen to another.

1. If you have not many screens you can use below code

   onPressed: () {
     Navigator.push(
       context,
       MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
     );
   }
2. If you have many screens you can manage your navigation from one place with named route

Add all routes in your initial screen like this

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => Screen0(),
        '/first': (context) => Screen1(),
        '/second': (context) => Screen2(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And then just put name of route you have defied and you are good to go.

```
class Screen0 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
        title: Text('Screen 0'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text('Go To Screen 1'),
              onPressed: () {
                //Navigate to Screen 1
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/first');
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text('Go To Screen 2'),
              onPressed: () {
                //Navigate to Screen 2
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```